# Deleting inverses in a matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix

I have initially a matrix, p:

```
# p is a matrix  

p
         A B
    [1,] 1 1
    [2,] 2 3
    [3,] 3 2
    [4,] 1 1
    [5,] 8 2
```

For a given matrix, I want to iterate through the rows and removing any inversions. So that the new matrix is:

```
p
             A B
        [1,] 1 1
        [2,] 2 3
        [3,] 8 2
```

This is what I got:

```
p<-unique(p) # gets rid of duplicates

output<-lapply(p, function(x){

  check<-which(p$A[x,] %in% p$B[x,])#is the value in row x of column A found in 
                                    #column B if so return the row number it was found in column B

  if (length(check)!=0 ){ 

    if(p$A[check,]== p$B[x]){ # now check if at the found row (check)of p$A is equal to p$B[x]
      p<-p[-check,] #if so remove that inverse 

    }


  }
}


  )
```

I get this message  `Error in which(p$A[x] %in% p$B[x]) :`

Why am I getting this Error? 
Is there a better way to find inversions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
 p <- unique(p)
 p[!duplicated(apply(p, 1, function(x) paste(sort(x), collapse=''))),]
 #     A B
 #[1,] 1 1
 #[2,] 2 3
 #[3,] 8 2
```

#### data

```
  p <- matrix(c(1,2,3,1,8, 1,3,2,1,2),
           dimnames=list(NULL, c("A", "B")), ncol=2)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear whether the order of values is important in your final output, but perhaps you can make use of `pmin` and `pmax`.

Here's an approach using those functions within "data.table":

```
library(data.table)
unique(as.data.table(p)[, list(A = pmin(A, B), B = pmax(A, B))])
#    A B
# 1: 1 1
# 2: 2 3
# 3: 2 8
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit unclear. I am assuming based on your example that you want to remove the row containing "3 2" because first value occurs in the second column (in a different row). In that case

```
check <- which(p[,1] %in% p[,2])
```

should return the rows that you want to delete. Your second round of checking is not needed. You could just delete the rows returned.